# How can I make auto browser or load localhost page when I start Apache in XAMPP Localhost

Tags: windows, xampp

My requirement is when I start apache in Windows with XAMPP, I need automatically pop up the browser with the localhost page. Is it possible to do by modifying the XAMPP files

Comment: Not possible AFAIK.

Comment: using a .bat file or looking like to start the xampp and then launch the browser with the desired url. the browser is the os business, not a xampp one. you may have to use some tricks to wait for the end of xampp start up before allowing the browser to be launched.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

Win+R ad write

```
shell:startup
```

Paste a shortcut of your favorite browser. It will launch the browser each time you run your computer.

After that define:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

as startup page for your browser.

(for ssl just replace http->https)